# Yosemite upgrade broke ruby.h

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-yosemite

Ever since upgrading to Yosemite, I get this error trying to build anything that includes `ruby.h`:

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [objects/if_ruby.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [first] Error 2
```

And sure enough, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/config.h` is indeed missing.

```
$ ls -laF /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel    714 Jul 29 21:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel    170 Jul 29 21:56 ../
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel    238 Jul 29 21:56 backward/
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   3360 Sep 21 15:25 debug.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   5553 Sep 21 15:25 defines.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel    881 Sep 21 15:25 digest.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   7628 Sep 21 15:25 dl.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel  14123 Sep 21 15:25 encoding.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel  32904 Sep 21 15:25 intern.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   5869 Sep 21 15:25 io.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   4522 Sep 21 15:25 missing.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel  37617 Sep 21 15:25 oniguruma.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   1502 Sep 21 15:25 re.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel    890 Sep 21 15:25 regex.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel  49734 Sep 21 15:25 ruby.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   4651 Sep 21 15:25 st.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel    374 Sep 21 15:25 subst.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   1102 Sep 21 15:25 thread.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   2139 Sep 21 15:25 util.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   1968 Sep 21 15:25 version.h
-rw-r--r--   2 root  wheel   1794 Sep 21 15:25 vm.h
```

Did the install accidentally a file?  Does Yosemite just ship with a busted Ruby header file set?

What's the best way to fix this?  Can I just unpack the source code in there to get the right headers?

Comment: Did you reinstall the Xcode tools? System upgrades have been known to force that need.

Comment: I reinstalled the Xcode command line tools, but still don't have a ruby/config.h

Comment: I don't think you have the correct Xcode installed.  Note the directory in the path:  `MacOSX10.9.sdk`  I'd expect to see something about 10.10.

Comment: CDub! Awesome. I reinstalled Xcode 6.0.1, and now it seems to work, and pulls ruby.h from a completely different location.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 18):

One note on this: I ran into this problem after upgrading to "OS X El Capitan". I installed the command line tools by running 'xcode-select --install'. After that, my ruby build environment started working again.

Answer (score 17):

For those who already had Xcode installed from the [Apple developers site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), running `xcode-select --install` doesn't work, since it will say that Xcode is already installed (Xcode already comes with the `CommandLineTools` bundled).

In my case, I fixed it by downloading the corresponding `CommandLineTools` from the same place, executing it, then going to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` and executing it too.

Answer (score 16):

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby
sudo ln -s ../universal-darwin15/ruby/config.h ./config.h
```

updates Nicholas Tsipanov's answer from 2014-10-18.

Comment: This is not working for me on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6; No such file or directory. I had to run `'xcode-select --install'` as described by Jesus instead.

Comment: Maybe your `MacOSX10.11.sdk` or `universal-darwin15` needs to be the correct path. It worked for me after ensuring correct path.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error, but installed "[Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10) for Xcode - Xcode 6.1](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#)" and installing worked fine after that.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Homebrew, `brew install ruby` is a fast workaround (it gets you a brand new ruby installation distinct from the one from Xcode).

Comment: @AboozarRajabi `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`   if you are on bash or some other shell where you will want to pipe it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by upgrading Ruby and also Rails to the latest versions (missing gems are reinstalled)

Comment: Wouldn't this potentially break other programs that assume you're using the version that comes with the OS?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby
sudo ln -s ../universal-darwin13/ruby/config.h ./config.h
```

Answer (score 1):

Xcode got messed up in the upgrade somehow.

I opened Xcode (which I never do otherwise) and it complained about all sorts of missing components.  So I let it go ahead and fix itself, and now all is well.

Props to CDub in the comments on OP for pointing to this as a potential source of weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Mojave 10.14.6. The answer here fixed the subject issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084238/284651

**Solution:**

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by pointing to correct path for Xcode developer tools.

Error before (Note the path to Xcode711.app instead of Xcode.app)

```
/Applications/Xcode711.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10:
```

Ran

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```