# Ruby and Rail Application Error when Running Bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am following a heroku tutorial where I created my rails app. I was asked to use Heroku to get my app live online.  But I have troubled to run the command Bundle install. It keeps giving me an error.

I tried to re-install Rail Bundler on my Terminal, but it shows me this error at the terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
In file included from
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10:
fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: When you see that error on Heroku, run `heroku logs --tail` so you can see the error (the details are hidden in production mode). Try `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: yes. That resolved the heroku issue, but I still have issue with my Gem Bundle install.

Comment: I ran the command 'gem install bundler'

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434642/yosemite-upgrade-broke-ruby-h it seems to be some OSX-specific error which I don't have experience with

Comment: Can you provide the log after migrating & trying to to run bundle again?