# Docker for Mac - mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby

Tags: ruby, docker

I updated XCode on my Mac and since then when starting Docker using `docker-sync-stack start` I get this error message:

```
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
```

I tried installing ruby with this: `brew install rbenv ruby-build` but this does not change anything.

Does anybody know how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out - after upgrading to Xcode 9 you must install the Command Line Tools for Xcode 9 as well.

Comment: Hit this issue when upgrading to Xcode 11 GM. Anyone found a solution? The `sudo xcode-select --install` command says I already have Command-Line Tools installed. Also tried manually downloading Xcode 11 Command-Line Tools from Developer Downloads. But I still get the error `mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h`

Answer (score 193, accepted):

For **Xcode 11 on macOS 10.14**, this can happen even after installing Xcode and installing command-line tools and accepting the license with

```
sudo xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

The issue is that Xcode 11 ships the macOS 10.15 SDK which includes headers for ruby2.6, but not for macOS 10.14's ruby2.3. You can verify that this is your problem by running

```
ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
```

which on macOS 10.14 with Xcode 11 prints the **non-existent** path

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0
```

However, Xcode 11 installs a macOS 10.14 SDK within `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOS10.14.sdk`. It isn't necessary to pollute the system directories by installing the old header files as suggested in other answers. Instead, by selecting that SDK, the appropriate ruby2.3 headers will be found:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
```

This should now correctly print

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0
```

Likewise, `gem install` should work while that SDK is selected.

To switch back to using the current Xcode 11 SDK, use

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: after export, it fixed the `ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'` but when I `gem install`, it still prints the wrong dir for file not found error

Comment: @Miranda can you verify that there's a `ruby.h` file in that path? Are you getting the exact same error message as in the question? What do `xcodebuild -version` and `xcrun --show-sdk-version` print?

Comment: `$ xcrun --show-sdk-version` give
`xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'SDKVersion' in SDK '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/'`, I end up using  @bdorfman 's solution of `rbenv`

Comment: @Miranda thank you for your report, I was able to reproduce the problem while `/Applications/Xcode.app` is selected using `xcode-select`. Selecting the command-line tools SDK instead worked for me (setting the variable is no longer required).

Comment: I searched for a couple of hours before finding this post, thank you.

Comment: Accepting the license helped me install CocoaPods as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Miranda run `xcode-select --install` to get Command Line Tools installed first. Then `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`. That will resolve this error. (Shared for future Googlers.)

Comment: Worked too on MacOS 10.15.7 and Xcode 11.7, I just had to run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`, because `ruby -rrbconfig` was printing the right path

Comment: I was having the same issue with Xcode 12.2 and because I named my Xcode 12.2 instead of the default Xcode, following these steps resolved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 137):

None of the other solutions worked for me, here's what I ran to resolve the issue on Mac OS 10.14.x:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Comment: Thanks, nothing else worked for me with macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: This likewise fixed the issue for me after upgrading to Xcode 11

Comment: Gem install package on Xcode 11 and Mojave was failing. This answer got me going . Should be selected as answer.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. This should be selected as the answer. I also tried the advise in this other thread to no avail (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434642/yosemite-upgrade-broke-ruby-h?noredirect=1&lq=1) before finding this answer.

Comment: My issue was in regards to installing cocoapods, and this fixed it for me. macOS 10.14.5 xcode 11.3.1 Thanks!

Comment: You are a savior my friend

Comment: Thx! This worked for me with MacOS 10.14.6 and Xcode 11.1

Comment: Awesome man, i can to this from another question and this is the only thing that worked for me on 10.14.6. Kudos :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I spent over 7hours trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks - this was the only thing that worked for me. 10.14.6. I first tried copying the Ruby 2.3 headers into the System Library Framework but SIP wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 36):

When upgrading XCode you need to install the Command-Line Tools and additionally accept the terms and conditions:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Then:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Comment: The first command was enough to get docker-sync-stack stop complaining. Actually the second command failed with "xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance"

Comment: As @Motin said, it seems like the second command doesn't work, but thankfully it wasn't necessary to get `docker-sync start` to stop complaining.

Comment: This wasn't enough for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 21):

As of Xcode 11, it seems like the ruby development headers are no longer included, so you will need to manually install them outside of Xcode Command Line Tools.

E.g. for me using rbenv i did

```
rbenv install 2.6.4
rbenv global 2.6.4
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Then ran bundle install and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Most importantly this worked for me. I'd also like to also note by adding `rbenv` in my CI workflow I was able to make great improvements (no need to install bundler using sudo anymore!) Thanks a lot @bdorfman

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason.  I even tried replacing "2.6.4" with "2.3.0".  When I look, there is no `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include` directory though the path up to "include" does exist.

Comment: thanks but I had to install the gem again, since there is nothing to bundle for docker-sync. The answer from @fnordl worked for me.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon Your environment probably isnt set up right. If its working correctly mkmf wont be looking for 2.3 any more itll be looking for whichever version you set. If you're still getting an error with the path `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3` it indicates that your env is still using the macOS system ruby and not rbenv's.

Comment: This also solved my Docker x Ruby issues

Answer (score 16):

For Xcode 11 I fixed this by also installing of `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` package.

Comment: Hey, I don't have this file. Where can I find it ?

Comment: Verify the pkg exists at the path Sergey provided. Check the path from root. Not in your users path. If is not there you can attempt to first install the command line tools: `xcode-select --install` and it should show up. Then, once you have the package at that path force the install like so `sudo installer -pkg macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /` (executing from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages)

Answer (score 16):

Single line command fix:

On OSX Mojave I ran the following command:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

and it fixed the issue.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I am prompted to add `-allowUntrusted` flag. But then it still failed at the end. The error message is `installer: The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)`

Comment: after trying every thing, you saved my life man thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem while installing fastlane. The tadman's answer is correct, but the command lines don't work for me with Xcode 10.2.1 (I'm not sure with other versions). You need to open Xcode, then open Preferences, select Locations and choose Command Line Tools. In my case, Command Line Tools field is empty.

Comment: This worked for me after searching for hours. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks alot Man, this worked for me too. My Xcode version is also 10.2.1

Answer (score 7):

As [@bdorfman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57929697/12107835) said in his comment, the Ruby headers are no longer included as of Xcode 11 build but they seem to try to make a new build for this as soon as possible (?): https://discuss.circleci.com/t/xcode-11-gm-seed-2-released/32505/12.

What worked for me was to use `rbenv` like @bdorfman said:

```
rbenv install 2.6.4
rbenv global 2.6.4
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

But with the extra step of adding `docker-sync` to your new ruby version. Since after you change the ruby version (for example)

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

And then running gem list:

```
$ gem list
bigdecimal (default: 1.4.1)
bundler (default: 1.17.2)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
csv (default: 3.0.9)
date (default: 2.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
did_you_mean (1.3.0)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
etc (default: 1.0.1)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.1.0)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.7)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.0.0)
json (default: 2.1.0)
logger (default: 1.3.0)
matrix (default: 0.1.0)
minitest (5.11.3)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
net-telnet (0.2.0)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
ostruct (default: 0.1.0)
power_assert (1.1.3)
prime (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
rake (12.3.2)
rdoc (default: 6.1.2)
rexml (default: 3.1.9)
rss (default: 0.2.7)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
shell (default: 0.7)
stringio (default: 0.0.2)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
sync (default: 0.5.0)
test-unit (3.2.9)
thwait (default: 0.1.0)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

(does not contains docker-sync)

If you run the gem install for docker-sync you will use the docker-sync for your rbenv managed ruby.

`$ gem install docker-sync`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a deeper insight into the issue:

> Mac OS X 10.14 has stopped placing the include libraries in their
>   usual location, /usr/include, keeping them only inside the XCode
>   directory.
>
> To confirm that this is the problem, simply run `ls /usr/include`. If
>   the result comes out empty, its really this problem.
>
> Apple ships a “legacy installer” for you to be able to install the
>   headers in the “old location”. 
>   To fix the problem just run this:
>
> `sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
>   -target /`

https://silvae86.github.io/sysadmin/mac/osx/mojave/beta/libxml2/2018/07/05/fixing-missing-headers-for-homebrew-in-mac-osx-mojave/

Answer (score 2):

Running `open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` in the terminal opens the package installation wizard. After properly installing was I able to proceed.

MacOS 10.4.4

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Close and Reopen Terminal

```
rvm install ruby-2.6

sudo gem install cocoapods
pod install
```

After completing right click on project top-left on android studio then click on Flutter -> Open IOS Module in Xcode