# How to build and install this gem package from source https://github.com/cmedley/terraforming?

Tags: ruby, macos-mojave

I want to build and use this github project https://github.com/cmedley/terraforming

I am trying to follow the instruction here https://github.com/cmedley/terraforming#development to build and run the package.

However, when I run `./script/setup` I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Did I miss anything obvious? I do not have much ruby experience and I am totally unfamiliar with Ruby ecosystem.

Comment: Do you have `bundler` gem installed? `gem install bundler`. This is a sort of "meta" library, it's used to install other libraries

Comment: I don't think so. I ran `gem list` and I do not see it in the output

Comment: So, give it a try. Having this gem installed is what gives you access to the `bundle` command (or `bundle install`, same thing) which installs the project dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error as shown in the question is solved by the suggestion from [Max Pleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2981429/max-pleaner).

```
 gem install bundler
```

However it soon encountered a second problem:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory:
>   /Users/antkong/Documents/Personal/wd/terraforming-assume-role/bin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/json-2.2.0/ext/json/ext/generator
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20191105-34055-mnnpg3.rb extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find
>   header files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> ```
> Gem files will remain installed in /Users/antkong/Documents/Personal/wd/terraforming-assume-role/bin/ruby/2.3.0/gems/json-2.2.0
> for inspection.
> Results logged to
> /Users/antkong/Documents/Personal/wd/terraforming-assume-role/bin/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/json-2.2.0/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing json (2.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
> Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.2.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
>
> In Gemfile:
>   coveralls was resolved to 0.8.21, which depends on
>     simplecov was resolved to 0.14.1, which depends on
>       json
> ```

The solution it to follow the instruction in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084238/58129

I reproduce the steps below:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
shareeditflag
```