# Errors when installing cocoapods with gem

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, rubygems

I am using macOS Mojave and when I try to install cocoapods using gem I am getting the following error.

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing cocoapods:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20200302-707-1iveybq.rb extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header
>   files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out

This error comes when I run the following commands.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

I have already installed xcode command line tools and I get the following message when I run `xcode-select --install`

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use
>   "Software Update" to install updates

I have also agreed to xcode license agreements with the command `sudo xcodebuild -license`

The error log in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out` gives the following

> current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteco$ mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.fra$
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1

What do I do to fix this issue ?

Comment: Do you have ruby installed? Try `ruby --version` from the command line

Comment: Hi yes I get this . ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

Comment: What are the contents of the log file? /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out

Comment: I included the error log

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at this [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377667/docker-for-mac-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby)

Comment: Thank you soo much. It worked. If you could draft an answer and link that question ill select it as the answer.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The answer for this can be found here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377667/docker-for-mac-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby) although it is unrelated to this question. Below is a snippet of the answer which works best.

For **Xcode 11 on macOS 10.14**, this can happen even after installing Xcode and installing command-line tools and accepting the license with

```
sudo xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

The issue is that Xcode 11 ships the macOS 10.15 SDK which includes headers for ruby2.6, but not for macOS 10.14's ruby2.3. You can verify that this is your problem by running

```
ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
```

which on macOS 10.14 with Xcode 11 prints the **non-existent** path

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0
```

However, Xcode 11 installs a macOS 10.14 SDK within `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOS10.14.sdk`. It isn't necessary to pollute the system directories by installing the old header files as suggested in other answers. Instead, by selecting that SDK, the appropriate ruby2.3 headers will be found:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
```

This should now correctly print

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0
```

Likewise, `gem install` should work while that SDK is selected.

To switch back to using the current Xcode 11 SDK, use

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: Many thanks , after 10 hours of searching i just found your solution and it's really helpful

Comment: @MoumenAlisawe Thank you. Happy To help :)

Comment: At my 10.14 path wasn't changing from 11.1 to 10.15. I had MacOSX10.14.sdk and MacOSX11.1.sdk In SDK folder. Changing MacOSX11.1.sdk name to MacOSX11.1.sdk.backup made its unused and running Xcode select successfully changed the path. I don't know any outcome of changing name or deleting that folder but it solved my question in short term.

Comment: Worked too on MacOS 10.15.7 and Xcode 11.7, I just had to run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`, because `ruby -rrbconfig` was printing the right path

Comment: This, combined with xcrun, and it worked for me.  The config.h file is in `universal-darwin20/ruby/` instead of `ruby/` in that rubyhdrdir

Comment: works for mac os monterey beta 2 and xcode 12.5

Answer (score 24):

For me use a command `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4` instead of `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Reference: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9568#issuecomment-599235420

Comment: I'm on catalina 10.15.5 and xcode 11.5. 
The missing headers business above wasn't the issue for me - but installing -v 1.8.4 did work so thanks.

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Run

   ```sh
   ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
   ```

   to figure out your ruby configuration.
2. If the output is a nonexistent MacOSX10.15 path.
   Like

   ```sh
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0
   ```

   then you should correct the configuration by doing next step.
3. Run

   ```sh
   sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
   ```
4. You can run

   ```sh
   ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
   ```

   again to see if the path has changed.
5. The output should be something like

   ```sh
   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0
   ```

Now you can run `gem install` to install cocoapods!

Comment: The only gem in this thread is your answer! Thank you, that worked for me with Big Sur

Comment: Also on Big Sur. Thanks for the step by step clarity!

Answer (score 12):

This helped/ worked for me like charm:

```
# brew cleanup -d -v    
# brew install cocoapods
```

P.S.: You should have Homebrew installed. You can use below command to install brew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Tried everything else on arm based Mac and nothing worked besides this. No problems so far. Brew coming in clutch again!

Answer (score 5):

Try this on mac os big sur

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

Comment: This is plagiarised from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63555919/7733418 , the older existing answer by kb920 but has less explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Try

1. Install homebrew via terminal.
2. After homebrew is successfully installed, type in the terminal

   $ brew install cocoapods

Answer (score 2):

just spent my day figuring out solution,
I am using **MacOS Big Sur Beta 8**.
to upgrade cocoapods with gem,
try this:

1. install rbenv

- `git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv`
- `cd ~/.rbenv && src/configure && make -C src`
- Add ~/.rbenv/bin to your $PATH for access to the rbenv command-line utility.
  see: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout
- make sure `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"` was added to your $PATH

2. `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develope`
3. `gem install cocoapods` should work like a charm!

Comment: This was the only thing that worked. Thanks ukiyoevega.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the latest version of CommandLineTools for Xcode to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I copied these commands from other threads. After trying several approaches answered above and in other threads. Only this one works for me.

1. Run this command and then close the Terminal

   curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
2. Run these commands one by one or just copy and paste them all in the Terminal. The latest version now is 3.1.0

   rvm install ruby-3.1.0

   rvm --default use 3.1.0

   sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is:

```
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -


curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

For detail pls refer: [another post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension/73375008#73375008)