# CocoaPods: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ios, rubygems, cocoapods

I have a trouble with cocoapods installation.
in terminal I'm running this: **sudo gem install cocoapods.**

Answer is this:

> ```
> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
>     current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/ext/ffi_c
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20200908-9483-1yecupd.rb extconf.rb
> mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1 for inspection.
> Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.13.1/gem_make.out
> ```

Can anybody hint what should I do? Thanx a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60481623/errors-when-installing-cocoapods-with-gem

Comment: Did you search for this error? I believe it has been answered many times. Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Error installing cocoapods: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)